# Change gunicorn worker timeout inside request

Tags: python, gunicorn, flask-restful

I have a slow request, and I want to change timeout for the worker during handling of that request and only for that request.

Basically, I have a flask application:

```
class Slow(Resource):

    def post(self):
        if slow_condition():
            gunicorn.how.to.extend.processing.time.here()
            do_something_slow()

api = Api(application)
api.add_resource(Slow, "/slow")
```

and I want to extend processing time if `slow_condition` returned `True`. How can I change timeout for the single request?

Answer (score 0):

No way.

`Flask` is just web framework. Framework doesn't know anything about production server and settings, workers etc. By the way to change sever configuration you need to reload all workers(restart `gunicorn`, `uWSGI`, `waitress` etc). So you can only increase [timeout parameter](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#timeout).

Comment: I understand that Flask has no idea about gunicorn on top of it. But I hoped for some way (socket? Signal? magical variable?) to be able to communicate with gunicorn.

Comment: @GeorgeShuklin you want to change worker timeout without reload. I don't think that's possible. But could you please explain what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: We have a good normal application server, where 30 seconds is more than enough for all tasks. But there is one call, which has a very rare and special condition (provision on a new server) which needs to wait for about 5-7 minutes. I can make it asynchronous, but keeping it synchronous would make client's life easier. It's a rare condition and I don't want to make other calls with worker timeout of 600 seconds...

Comment: @GeorgeShuklin please let me know if you solve the problem synchronously ❤️